# Can you think of a way to stop the generation of a core file WHILE it is happening?

Tags: linux, core-dump, ulimit

I was just wondering if you can think of a clever way to stop the creation of a `core` file while it is being produced.

I understand that there are several way to disable the creation like setting `ulimits` or setting the directory read only, but is there any way to stop it while the creation has already started?

Any way to simulate a disk full/permission denied to force the process to quit?

Answer (score 2):

I have just elementary linux knowledge, but would that work with getting the creation's pid via `top` and then `kill`ing it?

Comment: No it would not because a coring process gets into a D state (uninterruptable) and cannot be killed. So in case of a 15G+ process you would have to wait several minutes before you can restart a process